# Is it good practice to mutate a React SyntheticEvent as is bubbles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom react component as follows

```
const MyWidget = (props) => (
    <div>
        {props.options.map((option) => (
            <div onClick={(evt) => { onSelect(evt); }}>option</div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

and I want to pass the index of the div to the parent onSelect. The way I have been doing this in the past is:

```
const MyWidget = (props) => (
    <div>
        {props.options.map((option) => (
            <div onClick={(evt) => { onSelect(option, evt); }}>option</div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

but my widgets would behave more like native widgets if I did

```
const MyWidget = (props) => (
    <div>
        {props.options.map((option) => (
            <div onClick={(evt) => {
                evt.selectedOption = option;
                onSelect(evt); 
            }}>option</div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

so parents can register callbacks in the same way they would if they were using a native element. Are there any reasons why doing this is a bad idea? I guess name clashes would be one, but maybe this is mitigated by the tree structure, where it is the parent's responsibility to know what names are used in child events. Also, are Synthetic Events something that can be relied upon or are they an implementation feature that will change from time to time?